# Is it possible to get tax values for each item in a Virtuemart order?

Tags: joomla, joomla-extensions, virtuemart

Virtuemart calculates the tax based on shoppers address and add's this value to the jos_vm_orders table. But I need a "detailed" version of tax. I need to know the tax fore each line (jos_vm_order_item) of the order. Any suggestions? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I wish it were so...that tax is calculated and stored at the order level, not the line item detail.  I've had some luck in the past "reverse engineering" what the tax would be for a line item, but that's highly dependant on the business rules involved, and not generally reliable.